# Creation of asp.net websites artifacts in Teamcity from SVN repository

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity Professional Version 4.5.4 (build 9071) at work to build my asp.net web application project.

My solution file consists of several projects (e.g. web application, unit tests, some web service project, etc).

I want to create an artifact consisting of my web application (the others can be ignore for now), so I have the following configuration on teamcity (deviating from the default values):

- General Settings

  - Artifact Paths: trunk\project-src\intranet-webapp***=>WebAppArtifact
- Version control settings (SVN)

  - Automatically checkout on agent
- Runner (sln2008)

  - Targets: Clean Publish

It builds my artifacts just fine, but there is a **big problem**: The artifact keeps the ".svn" folders and the .cs (C# code-behind) files in it.

I expected that with the "Publish" target in my runner, I would have exactly what the "Publish project" menu in VS 2008 does: copies the compiled project to some location without the code-behind files and no .svn folders.

Could anyone tell me what configuration am I missing?

Comment: Did you figure out how to exclude the codebehind files from the artifacts folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will use checkout on server, there will be no .svn directories.